# How to load a Google Maps baselayer in Leaflet (after june 2018)?

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, maps

I have a leaflet map in my website using Google satellite images as a base map.  After June 11 2018, the google map tiles cant be accessed without an api key.  The tiles can currently be accessed through Leaflet JS using the following javascript.

```
googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

How will I include my api key to be able to continue to access map tiles from Leaflet after June 11 2018?

Comment: This question on the gis board may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228162/giving-google-api-key-in-google-street-map-used-by-leaflet-map/228163

Comment: Damn, I missed that duplicate. Maybe I should copy-paste my answer in there, and vote to close this one?

Answer (score 23):

Loading tiles from Google Maps by just specifying the URL of an *undocumented* API is against the [Google Maps terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions). Let me quote from them:

> 10. License Restrictions.
>
> 10.1 Administrative Restrictions.
>
> No access to APIs or Content except through the Service. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service.
>   For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through
>   interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces)
>   other than the Maps API(s).

You will also note that the tile URLs are **not** documented in their [development documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) (as of early june 2018).

What you *can* do, however, is load one instance of a Google Map per instance of Leaflet, keep both map sizes and centers in sync, and use mutation observers to monitor whenever the Google Map instance loads a tile, so you can rip it off the Google Map DOM tree and put it in the Leaflet DOM tree (if you just use tricky CSS to show Leaflet on top of Google Maps, eventually you'll run into problems about syncing the zoom animations of both).

If this sounds too scary, don't worry. [Leaflet.GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/) does all the heavy lifting for you. Let me quote from its readme:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" async defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@latest/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@latest/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js'></script>
```

---

```
var roads = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ type: 'roadmap' }).addTo(map);
```

Note that there's a perfectly obvious place for your API key (which is your main worry), and that GoogleMutant only uses the public (and documented) API (which you should worry about, too, since it's in the ToS).

Comment: The problem that Google Mutant sometimes leaving gray tiles (untiled parts of map). Any hope to solve this problem with gray tiles in future?