# how to add google map styles to leaflet js?

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, gis, react-leaflet

I'm trying to add google map styles into leaflet but I'm confused on how to do it:
[image: google map platform].

In the leaflet, the tilelayer url is like this. how to get tilelayer like this on google map styles?
[image]

I haven't found an answer how to do it and what I expect is a style map on a leaflet like this:
[image]

Is this an impossible thing to do or not?

Comment: Leaflet is a map display library, which means it displays maps, not modifies them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672846/ . Read GoogleMutant's documentation about styling.